# How should I set the default virtualhost?

Tags: apache, virtualhost, httpd.conf

I want to run 2 websites.
One for www.example.com, and the other for everything else (www.example2.com, www.example3.com)

How I do it?

I tried:

```
<virtualhost *:80>
ServerName www.example.com
</virtualhost>
<virtualhost>
#no server name
</virtualhost>
```

But I ALWAYS get the second website.
Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

The default host that is the one that is **first**

```
# Default host (must be first)
<virtualhost *:80>    
    # I use localhost.localdomain, but any host name not matching later hosts gets handled here
    Servername localhost.localdomain
    DocumentRoot /home/www/default_site
    ...
</virtualhost>
<virtualhost *:80>
    ServerName www.example.com
</virtualhost>
```